# Архитектура мобильного приложения с удаленной БД

Tags: android, база-данных, android-room, пагинация

Я хочу сделать приложение, которое загружает все БД на телефон, но изменения на удаленной БД должны отражаться и в приложении. Удаленная БД представляет с собой бесплатный хост с простыми PHP скриптами и MySQL. Допустим там может быть много каких-то данных и мне их надо показать как список (тут надо использовать пагинацию с которой я еще не разобрался, если поможете и тут то спасибо).
Так вот, Постоянно ее подгружать полностью как-то не красиво выглядит, даже если предположить что количество элементов будет небольшим. Основной вопрос состоит в том как правильно подгружать базу данных и как следить за изменениями в реальном времени, постоянно пинговать хост и спрашивать? По триггерам делать таблицу изменений и плясать от нее? Но ее же может тоже много накопиться. Разъясните пожалуйста эти моменты на проверку локальной БД на актуальность

P.S. в теории JSON файл который присылается на локальную машину может быть так же большим, потому что допустим я хочу сделать график изменений этих элементов. Для этого мне нужно будет подкачивать таблицу их изменений за каждый день, что не маленький объем данных. Что лучше: заморачиваться со стримами, Reader и парсить JSON или через for просто доставать по 1-10 строк данных?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь изобрести какой-то велосипед. Ради изменения 1 строчки данных вы готовы загружать на телефон ВСЮ БД? Трафик не жалко? Есть же REST, GraphQL

Comment: @ArchDemon как раз и понимаю, что постоянная подкачка лишнего - это глупость. Потому и спрашиваю: как определить что надо подкачивать

Comment: не делать локальную копию в принципе. Отображать только те данные, которые запросил пользователь.

Comment: @ArchDemon ладно, а как бы ты посоветовал сделать отображение изменчивого объекта? Сервисом постоянно спрашивать сервер?

Comment: Как вариант. Есть ещё WebSocket и Server Sent Events (SSE)

Comment: Да, можно не делать локальную копию. Все зависит от задачи. Вам решать. Не нужно подгружать данные, чтобы построить отчет. Отчет должен делаться на сервере и отдаваться в готовом виде. Раньше использовали связку BaseAdapter (или его потомки)/ListView, сейчас RecycleView со своим адаптером. По поводу обновления не подскажу, также зависит от задачи,  самый примитивный способ кнопка для пользователя "Обновить".